# The right record access implementation

Tags: solr, lucene

I am looking into indexing engines, specifically Apache Lucene Solr. We are willing to use it for our searches, yet one of the problems solved by our frameworks search is row-level access.

Solr does not provide record access out of the box:

> <...> Solr does not concern itself with security either at the document level or the communication level.

And in the section about document level security: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity#Document_Level_Security

There are few suggestions - either use Manifold CF (which is highly undocumented and seems in a very pre-beta stage) or write your own request handler/search component (that part is marked as stub) - I guess that the later one would have bigger impact on performance.

So I assume not much is being done in this field.

In the recently released 4.0 version of Solr, they have introduced joining two indexed entities. Joining might seem a nice idea, since our framework also does a join to know whether the record is accessible for the user. The problem here is that sometimes we do a inner join, and sometimes and outer (depending on the optimistic (everything what's not forbidden is allowed) or pessimistic (everything is forbidden only what is explicitly allowed) security setting in the scope).

To give a better understanding of what our structure looks like:

**Documents**

```
DocumentNr | Name
------------------
1          | Foo
2          | Bar
```

**DocumentRecordAccess**

```
DocumentNr | UserNr | AllowRead | AllowUpdate | AllowDelete
------------------------------------------------------------
1          | 1      | 1         | 1           | 0
```

So for example the generated query for the Documents in pessimistic security setting would be:

```
SELECT * FROM Documents AS d 
INNER JOIN DocumentRecordAccess AS dra ON dra.DocumentNr=d.DocumentNr AND dra.AllowRead=1 AND dra.UserNr=1
```

This would return only the foo, but not the bar. And in optimistic setting:

```
SELECT * FROM Documents AS d 
LEFT JOIN DocumentRecordAccess AS dra ON dra.DocumentNr=d.DocumentNr AND dra.AllowRead=1 AND dra.UserNr=1
```

Returning both - the Foo and the Bar.

Coming back to my question - maybe someone has already done this and can share their insight and experience?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am afraid there's no easy solution here. You will have to sacrifice something to get ACLs working together with the search.

1. If your corpus size is small (I'd say up to 10K documents), you could create a cached bit set of forbidden (or allowed, whichever less verbose) documents and send relevant filter query `(+*:* -DocumentNr:1 ... -DocumentNr:X)`. Needless to say, this doesn't scale. Sending large queries will make the search a bit slower, but this is manageable (up to a point of course). Query parsing [is cheap](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201204.mbox/%3CCAN4YXvdUFLvq3E2760esuk8_i_Z8-G-vA-mWDaFFVtzvXrd0_Q@mail.gmail.com%3E).
2. If you can somehow group these documents and apply ACLs on document groups, this would allow cutting on query length and the above approach would fit perfectly. This is pretty much what we are using - our solution implements taxonomy and has taxonomy permissions done via `fq` query.
3. If you don't need to show the overall result set count, you can run your query and filter the result set on the client side. Again, not perfect.
4. You can also denormalize your data structures and store both tables flattened in a single document like this:

   DocumentNr: 1
   Name: Foo
   Allowed_users: u1, u2, u3 (or Forbidden_users: ...)

   The rest is as easy as sending user id with your query.

   Above is only viable if the ACLs are rarely changing **and** you can afford reindexing the entire corpus when they do.
5. You could write a custom query filter which would have cached `BitSet`s of allowed or forbidden documents by user(group?) retrieved from the database. This would require not only providing DB access for Solr webapp but also extending/repackaging the .war which comes with Solr. While this is relatively easy, the [harder part would be cache invalidation](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html): main app should somehow signal Solr app when ACL data gets changed.

Options 1 and 2 are probably more reasonable if you can put Solr and your app onto the same JVM and use [javabin](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/javabin) driver.

It's hard to advice more without knowing the specifics of the corpus/ACLs.

Comment: I've been part of an implementation of suggestion (4) above, and it worked fine.  We used a combination of Groups and individual Users, so it was not as bad when Group membership changed.  We did also implement a custom request handler that would fetch permissions, and it did slightly affect performance, but was worth it.

Answer (score 3):

I am agree with mindas, what he has suggested (sol-4),  i have implemented my solution the same way,but the difference is i have few different type of ACLs. At usergroup level,user level and even document level too (private access).

The solution is working fine. But the main concern in my case is that ACLs gets changed frequently and that needs to be updated in the index,mean while search performance should not get affected too.

I am trying to manage this with load balancing and adding few more nodes into the cluster.

mindas,unicron can you please put your thoughts on this?

Comment: Well, there's nothing much to add to what you said. In cases where _eventual_ ACL consistency is sufficient (and I hope it is for majority of cases) the reindexing is not the end of the world. But if you have millions of documents to reindex, then it becomes real pain...

Comment: Mindas, i am afraid that i need to update few million records per minute in to index, because i am working on document management system,where ACLs are tightly coupled with the documents.If i add one user or remove 1 user from the project, i need to update all the documents in the project to reflect these changes,because we have flat data data representation. I am planning to do this using JMS. But still can you suggest anything which can reduce my pain ?

Comment: How about other options I suggested (e.g. option 5)? By the way, it would probably be more polite/correct to create a separate question (and list all peculiarities/differences) instead of piggy-backing on this one.