# Is Solr search capable of filtering data within returned result SOLR documents?

Tags: java, join, indexing, solr, solrj

I have indexed an entity. It has many facets. Following is the entity...

Entity: Person

Single-valued facet: Name

Multi-valued Facets: Brand, Role, Permission

Example :

Person {id, Name, Brand, Role, Permission}

Name: Person1

Brand : B1, B2, B3

Role : R1, R2, R3

Permission : P1, P2, P3

I have 2 users in my system. User U1 and U2.

When I perform Solr search matching Name of person as 'Person1', this document is returned.

Now I want document data filtering when this document is returned as a result of solr search.

User U1 has permission to see only Brand B1 and he should not view Brand B2 and B3.

User U2 has permission to view brand B3 only, he should not view Brand B1 and B2.

Same is the case with other multi-valued facets.
Is it possible to filter the data in such a way?

Comment: What about doing a boolean filtered query on the "permission" field as the following (for user U1): fq=( permission:B1 AND NOT ( permission:B2 OR permission: B3) )?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no out of the box solution. Google for 'solr acl' you will find leads, like [this](http://lucidworks.com/blog/custom-security-filtering-in-solr/). Also look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866089/the-right-record-access-implementation).